# Two multimeters in continuity mode, only 1 buzzer

Tags: multimeter, piezo-buzzer, continuity

I have two identical digital multimeters both with new batteries.

I set both to continuity mode and connected the leads to each other.

Only one of the meters buzzers went off.

They both work independently.

I am puzzled.

Comment: ....the buzzer is broken? If you set the reading to Ohms, do they both read about zero?

Comment: 0.2Ω on the buzzing meter and 0.6Ω on the quiet meter

Comment: Did you connect the meters *to each other*, or did you just short the leads on each meter individually?

Comment: @DaveTweed both. To themselves, both buzz. To each other, only left meter buzzes

Comment: Why did you think that connecting them to each other would do anything useful?

Comment: I did it by mistake then was interested in the outcome - nothing useful other than satisfying my curiousity

Comment: Did you try reversing the polarity of the connection? I.e., instead of connecting red-red and black-black, connect red-black in both directions.

Comment: black-black/red-red quiet, black-red/black-red buzz

Comment: Well, MMs are active parts. Continuity testing/resistance metering is for passive parts.

Comment: ... was interested in the outcome. Excellent! First requirement for an engineer.

Comment: I tried this with a Klein MM325 and Craftsman 82141 multimeters. Neither beeped.
I did measure the voltage of each in a simple circuit. **2.16 VDC for the Klein** and **2.45 VDC for the Craftsman.** I tried to discern which is the polarity that sends the voltage and which receives. Testing either polarity got me 0 voltage. The DAC inside the multimeter is smarter than the simple switch that I imagined in my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Continuity Mode' is not a well defined function. It is actually a resistance measurement, set to beep for resistance below some threshold, and silence above that threshold.

In making a resistance measurement, a meter sends out a small current, 1 mA would not be surprising, and measures the voltage across the probes. If the continuity reading used a 100 Ω threshold, then it would beep for <100 mV measured across the probes, and stay silent above 100 mV.

When you connect two meters together, you can assume that their resistance measuring currents will not be identical, although nominally the same. The higher current one is likely to overpower the low current one, resulting in a measured voltage that one sees as sub-threshold, the other as super-threshhold.

Try putting one on continuity, the other on current, then swap. Also, get a third meter, and measure the probe voltages when your two continuity meters are connected.